# how to create multiple join in ef?

Tags: entity-framework

i have 3 tables in my db and 2 of these tables have a key in another one .

how can i create this 2 join in entity frame work(version 5 or 6 , database first)?

```
tbl1
-----------
tbl1ID
tbl1name                                           tbl3
                                                   -----------
                                                    tbl3ID
        ---inner join on tbl1ID and tbl2ID --->     tbl1ID       
                                                    tbl2ID
                                                    tbl3name
tbl2
-----------
tbl2ID
tbl2name
```

i want this result:

```
  result (columns)
  --------------------
  tbl1ID
  tbl2ID       
  tbl3ID
  tbl1name
  tbl2name
  tbl3name
```

Comment: A class model (with navigation properties) would be a better starting point. You probably don't even have to write out joins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

following code snippets may help you:

```
(from c in db.tbl1
join d in db.tbl3 on c.tbl1ID equals d.tbl1ID
join e in db.tbl2 on d.tbl2ID equals e.tbl2ID
select new { c.tbl1ID, d.tbl2ID, e.tbl3ID, c.tbl1Name, d.tbl2Name, e.tbl3Name}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using entity framework then you doesn't need to use join you can directly access the results from tbl3 object. Use following:

```
tbl3.tlb1.tbl1ID
tbl3.tbl2.tbl2ID
tbl3ID,
tbl3.tlb1.tbl1name,
tbl3.tbl2.tbl2name,
tbl3name
```